# Programming pointer issue

Tags: c, function, pointers, project

I was assigned to do a project that reads from a file and according to the char it inputs is what it does with the following values so if it reads + it will add the next two numbers or if its an H it'll print out the instructions. Im having trouble with printing the results to another file I pass the pointer to each function as follows `void add(int a, int b, FILE *print)`, and invoke it as follows.. `add(a, b, printer)`, it worked perfectly before I tried printing out to a file. The error I get is...

in function add:

```
error : incompatible type for argument 1 of fprintf
expected 'struct FILE *' but argument is of type 'FILE'
```

this happens too all my functions.

here's the code. Thanks !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void add(int a, int b, FILE *print);
void add(int a, int b, FILE *print)
{
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    printf("%i + %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
    fprintf(*print, "%i + %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
}
void subtract(int a, int b, FILE *print);
void subtract(int a, int b, FILE *print)
{
    int c;
    c = a - b;
    printf("%i - %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
    fprintf(*print, "%i - %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
}
void multiply(int a, int b, FILE *print);
void multiply(int a, int b, FILE *print)
{
    int c;
    c = a * b;
    printf("%i * %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
    fprintf(*print, "%i * %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
}
void divide(int a, int b, FILE *print);
void divide(int a, int b, FILE *print)
{
    double c;
    c = (double)(a/b);
    printf("%i - %i = %.1lf\n\n", a, b, c);
    fprintf(*print, "%i - %i = %.1lf\n\n", a, b, c);
}
void help(FILE *print);
void help(FILE *print)
{
    printf("+ i j [Integer Add]\t\tAdds integers i and j and print out result\n\n");
    printf("* i j [Integer Multiply]\tMultiply integers i and j and print out result\n\n");
    printf("- i j [Integer Subtract ]\tSubtract integer j from i and print out result\n\n");
    printf("/ i j [Integer Divide ]\t\tDivide integer i by j and print out result of integer    division\n\n");
    printf("H [Help ]\t\t\tPrint a short synopsis of all the available commands\n\n");
    printf("Q [Quit ]\t\t\tQuit\n\n");
    printf("\n\n");
    fprintf(*print, "+ i j [Integer Add]\t\tAdds integers i and j and print out result\n\n");
    fprintf(*print, "* i j [Integer Multiply]\tMultiply integers i and j and print out result\n\n");
    fprintf(*print, "- i j [Integer Subtract ]\tSubtract integer j from i and print out result\n\n");
    fprintf(*print, "/ i j [Integer Divide ]\t\tDivide integer i by j and print out result of integer division\n\n");
    fprintf(*print, "H [Help ]\t\t\tPrint a short synopsis of all the available commands\n\n");
    fprintf(*print, "Q [Quit ]\t\t\tQuit\n\n");
    fprintf(*print, "\n\n");
}
char quit(void);
char quit(void)
{
    char user;
    printf("Do you really want to quit?(y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &user);
    return user;
}

int main()
{

char trigger;
char user;
char fname;
char lname;
int a;
int b;

FILE *myPointer;
FILE *printer;
myPointer = fopen("CommandsProj1.dat", "r");
printer = fopen("results.dat", "w");

if (myPointer == NULL)
{
    printf("error opening the file");
    fprintf(printer, "error opening the file");
}
else
{
    fscanf(myPointer, " %c%c", &fname, &lname);
    printf("Initials %c%c\n\n\n", fname, lname);

    while(user != 'y')
    {
        fscanf(myPointer, " %c", &trigger);
        switch(trigger)
        {
            case '+':
                    fscanf(myPointer, "%i%i", &a,&b);
                    add(a,b,myPointer);
                    break;
            case '-':
                    fscanf(myPointer, "%i%i", &a, &b);
                    subtract(a,b,myPointer);
                    break;
            case '/':
                    fscanf(myPointer, "%i%i", &a,&b);
                    divide(a,b,myPointer);
                    break;
            case '*':
                    fscanf(myPointer, "%i%i", &a,&b);
                    multiply(a,b,myPointer);
                    break;
            case 'H':
                    help(myPointer);
                    break;
            case 'Q':
                    user = quit();
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do as the error says, change *print to print in fprintf.

Answer (score 2):

You're dereferencing the `FILE *` to `fprintf`. This is not necessary (and even erroneous) as `fprintf` expects a pointer. Change the printing lines to:

```
fprintf(print, ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change all *print to print in fprintf function call then everything will be okay.

**Full Working Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void add(int a, int b, FILE *print);
void add(int a, int b, FILE *print)
{
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    printf("%i + %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
    fprintf(print, "%i + %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
}
void subtract(int a, int b, FILE *print);
void subtract(int a, int b, FILE *print)
{
    int c;
    c = a - b;
    printf("%i - %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
    fprintf(print, "%i - %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
}
void multiply(int a, int b, FILE *print);
void multiply(int a, int b, FILE *print)
{
    int c;
    c = a * b;
    printf("%i * %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
    fprintf(print, "%i * %i = %i\n\n", a, b, c);
}
void divide(int a, int b, FILE *print);
void divide(int a, int b, FILE *print)
{
    double c;
    c = (double)(a/b);
    printf("%i - %i = %.1lf\n\n", a, b, c);
    fprintf(print, "%i - %i = %.1lf\n\n", a, b, c);
}
void help(FILE *print);
void help(FILE *print)
{
    printf("+ i j [Integer Add]\t\tAdds integers i and j and print out result\n\n");
    printf("* i j [Integer Multiply]\tMultiply integers i and j and print out result\n\n");
    printf("- i j [Integer Subtract ]\tSubtract integer j from i and print out result\n\n");
    printf("/ i j [Integer Divide ]\t\tDivide integer i by j and print out result of integer    division\n\n");
    printf("H [Help ]\t\t\tPrint a short synopsis of all the available commands\n\n");
    printf("Q [Quit ]\t\t\tQuit\n\n");
    printf("\n\n");
    fprintf(print, "+ i j [Integer Add]\t\tAdds integers i and j and print out result\n\n");
    fprintf(print, "* i j [Integer Multiply]\tMultiply integers i and j and print out result\n\n");
    fprintf(print, "- i j [Integer Subtract ]\tSubtract integer j from i and print out result\n\n");
    fprintf(print, "/ i j [Integer Divide ]\t\tDivide integer i by j and print out result of integer division\n\n");
    fprintf(print, "H [Help ]\t\t\tPrint a short synopsis of all the available commands\n\n");
    fprintf(print, "Q [Quit ]\t\t\tQuit\n\n");
    fprintf(print, "\n\n");
}
char quit(void);
char quit(void)
{
    char user;
    printf("Do you really want to quit?(y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &user);
    return user;
}

int main()
{

char trigger;
char user;
char fname;
char lname;
int a;
int b;

FILE *myPointer;
FILE *printer;
myPointer = fopen("CommandsProj1.dat", "r");
printer = fopen("results.dat", "w");

if (myPointer == NULL)
{
    printf("error opening the file");
    fprintf(printer, "error opening the file");
}
else
{
    fscanf(myPointer, " %c%c", &fname, &lname);
    printf("Initials %c%c\n\n\n", fname, lname);

    while(user != 'y')
    {
        fscanf(myPointer, " %c", &trigger);
        switch(trigger)
        {
            case '+':
                    fscanf(myPointer, "%i%i", &a,&b);
                    add(a,b,myPointer);
                    break;
            case '-':
                    fscanf(myPointer, "%i%i", &a, &b);
                    subtract(a,b,myPointer);
                    break;
            case '/':
                    fscanf(myPointer, "%i%i", &a,&b);
                    divide(a,b,myPointer);
                    break;
            case '*':
                    fscanf(myPointer, "%i%i", &a,&b);
                    multiply(a,b,myPointer);
                    break;
            case 'H':
                    help(myPointer);
                    break;
            case 'Q':
                    user = quit();
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to replace *print with print only because it is passes as ppointer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about `fprintf(*print,...);`

I think you didn't distinguish the  `*` in the definition and declaration statement with the `*` in de-reference statement.

Consider this code segment:

```
int a=10;
int *p =a;
printf("%d",*p);
```

In `int *p =a;`, this is a definition statement, the `*` here indicates that the p is a pointer.

In `printf("%d",*p);`, there is also a `*` before `p`, but here it is an operator, it get the value where p points to( a's value 10 here).

So in `fprintf(...);` the first argument should be a pointer, not something the pointer points to. Then you should use the pointer `print` you passed in.